# Using Google Apps Directory Sync with existing system in place

Tags: active-directory, g-suite

We use Google Apps for our systems and have an Active Directory in place as well. The AD is not being used as of now but we really want to get started with using it.

A few questions re. using Google Apps Directory Sync in this scenario

The document says all my info from the AD will stay the same but the one in Google Apps will change to match it.

1. I have some users defined in Google Apps but not in the AD. Is there any way I can preserve those during the sync? Or do I absolutely have to create them on AD first?
2. I understand I'll have to use the user provisioning API to ensure 2-way sync. Is there an easier option to this?

Thanks.

**For 1**
I did find exclusion rules but the example provided in the doc is for just a single user in Google Apps and missing from LDAP. There is no rule for multiple users?

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a one time sync or are you planning to run Google Apps Directory Sync regularly?

I didn't understand what you meant in second bullet. By 2-way sync, do you mean you want to sync from Google Apps to AD?

Comment: The sync will run regularly. By 2-way sync I mean if I create a user in Google Apps, it should be added to the AD as well. I know I can have a web interface which creates users in both (using Provisioning API). But wanted to know if there is a program which does this already.

Comment: Google Apps Directory Sync does not provide 2-Way sync, probably you can check on appropriate Google Help forum on this. For excluding your users, probably you can check if there is any pattern on all of those users (or you can add some unique prefix/suffix yourself manually if its not a huge manual task) and use Regex based user exclusion in the user exclusion page.